# Why does opening and closing a window speed up my application? - C# WPF MVVM Observer Pattern

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, visual-studio-2015, observer-pattern

I have a C# WPF application built with Visual Studio 2015.  I'm using MVVM and the Observer Pattern.

My Provider is a user control called 'ucClientFilter1ViewModel' that contains two text box controls where the user can search for a client(s):

```
namespace NSUCClientControls
{
    public class ucClientFilter1ViewModel : ViewModelBase, IObservable<ClientFilterParameter>
    {
        private string filterLocation;

        private string whereSearch1;
        private string whereSearch2;

        private List<IObserver<ClientFilterParameter>> observers;

        public ucClientFilter1ViewModel()
        {
            observers = new List<IObserver<ClientFilterParameter>>();
        }

        public string FilterLocation
        {
            get { return filterLocation; }
            set { filterLocation = value; }
        }

        public string WhereSearch1
        {
            get { return whereSearch1; }
            set
            {
                whereSearch1 = value;
                TestUpdateGrid(filterLocation);
            }
        }

        public string WhereSearch2
        {
            get { return whereSearch2; }
            set
            {
                whereSearch2 = value;
                TestUpdateGrid(filterLocation);
            }
        }

        private void TestUpdateGrid(string _filterLocation)
        {
            var filterInfo = new ClientFilterParameter(this);
            foreach (var observer in observers)
            {
                observer.OnNext(filterInfo);
            }
        }

        public IDisposable Subscribe(IObserver<ClientFilterParameter> observer)
        {
            // Check whether observer is already registered.  If not, add it
            if (!observers.Contains(observer))
            {
                observers.Add(observer);

                // Provide observer with existing data
                var filterInfo = new ClientFilterParameter(this);
                observer.OnNext(filterInfo);
            }
            return new Unsubscriber<ClientFilterParameter>(observers, observer);
        }

        internal class Unsubscriber<ClientFilterParameter> : IDisposable
        {
            private IObserver<ClientFilterParameter> observer;
            private List<IObserver<ClientFilterParameter>> observers;

            public Unsubscriber(List<IObserver<ClientFilterParameter>> _observers, IObserver<ClientFilterParameter> _observer)
            {
                observers = _observers;
                observer = _observer;
            }

            public void Dispose()
            {
                if (observers.Contains(observer))
                {
                    observers.Remove(observer);
                }
            }
        }

    }
}
```

My Observer is a user control called 'ucClientGrid1ViewModel' that contains a datagrid where the search results are displayed.

```
namespace NSUCClientControls
{
    public class ucClientGrid1ViewModel : ViewModelBase, IObserver<ClientFilterParameter>
    {
        private IDisposable cancellation;
        private ObservableCollection<Client> clientsMultiple;

        public ucClientGrid1ViewModel()
        {
        }

        public ObservableCollection<Client> ClientsMultiple
        {
            get
            {
                var myClientDataAccess = new ClientDataAccess();
                clientsMultiple = myClientDataAccess.GetClientListFromSQL_Test2();
                return clientsMultiple;
            }
            set
            {
            }
        }

        public virtual void Subscribe(ucClientFilter1ViewModel provider)
        {
            cancellation = provider.Subscribe(this);
        }

        public void OnNext(ClientFilterParameter myFilter)
        {
            OnPropertyChanged("ClientsMultiple");

            var myDummyWindow = new dummyWindow();
            myDummyWindow.Show();
            myDummyWindow.Close();
        }

        public void OnError(Exception error)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }

        public void OnCompleted()
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }

    }
}
```

This all works and I get the search results that I am expecting.  But what I don't understand is why the inclusion of the following lines actually speed things up!

```
            var myDummyWindow = new dummyWindow();
            myDummyWindow.Show();
            myDummyWindow.Close();
```

I'm new to MVVM and the observer pattern, so as I was writing the code I had included message boxes at various points to help me to follow the flow of it.  It was all working as expected.  Then I removed the message boxes and it still worked but the application was pausing at the end before you could continue to keep searching.

Putting a message box back in at the end prevented this pause.  Replacing the message box with a "DummyWindow" that just opens and closes has the same affect and prevents the pause at the end.  This is what I currently have but I'd rather not leave this in there.

Presumably opening the window causes something else to happen which stops some redundant process, and this then prevents the pause?  What else could I do to prevent the pause at the end, without using this DummyWindow?

I've tried searching on here and with Bing with no luck.

Thanks in advance!

Edit:

ViewModelBase...

```
namespace NSCommon
{
    public abstract class ViewModelBase : INotifyPropertyChanged, IDisposable
    {
        protected ViewModelBase()
        {
        }

        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

        protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
        {
            PropertyChangedEventHandler handler = PropertyChanged;

            if (handler != null)
            {
                var e = new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName);
                handler(this, e);
            }
        }

        public void Dispose()
        {
            OnDispose();
        }

        protected virtual void OnDispose()
        {
        }
    }
}
```

ClientFilterParameter...

```
namespace NSCommon
{
    public class ClientFilterParameter
    {
        public ClientFilterParameter(ucClientFilter1ViewModel myFilter)
        {
            FilterLocation = myFilter.FilterLocation;
            WhereSearch1 = myFilter.WhereSearch1;
            WhereSearch2 = myFilter.WhereSearch2;
        }

        private string filterLocation;
        private string whereSearch1;
        private string whereSearch2;

        public string FilterLocation
        {
            get { return filterLocation; }
            set { filterLocation = value; }
        }

        public string WhereSearch1
        {
            get { return whereSearch1; }
            set { whereSearch1 = value; }
        }

        public string WhereSearch2
        {
            get { return whereSearch2; }
            set { whereSearch2 = value; }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Please provide implementation of `ViewModelBase` and `ClientFilterParameter `

Comment: @Alireza - Thanks for looking at this.  I've added the code for ViewModelBase and ClientFilterParameter.